# Elasticsearch query: match word in array of sentences

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I have a field that is an array of sentences (string). I'd like to search inside the array if the word is in the sentences.

```
"fields": {
           "title": [
              "The book of the world"
           ]
        }
```

The simple query "book" does not return the expected result:

```
GET catalog/_search
  {
    "fields" : "title",
    "query":{
       "match" : {
          "title":"book"
       }
     }
}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you show the mappings?

GET catalog/_mapping

Comment: the mapping is : `"tokenizer": "standard"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure an analyzer before adding data to your index.

The analyzer is the thing that "split" your sentence as token (here: "the" "book" "of" "the" "world" or by removing stop words "book" "world").

Please read documentation at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Also pay attention how Elasticsearch deals with array: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html

Comment: The default analyzer was overloaded by one that does not split the content

Answer (score 1):

The field name in that case is fields.title not title.

Try:

```
GET catalog/_search
{
    "fields" : "fields.title",
    "query":{
       "match" : {
          "fields.title":"book"
       }
     } 
}
```